# Diferencia DataTable y Grid de jQuery

Tags: c#, datatables

Soy principiante en esto de la programación Web y estoy haciendo un proyecto. Mi objetivo es recolectar datos de una tabla de una base de datos muy extensa y que se muestren en una página Web . Utilizo **c#** y me han dicho que para esto estaría bien utilizar un **grid** con **jQuery**, pero también he visto a gente que utiliza un `DataTable`.

¿Qué sería más recomendable utilizar y qué diferencia hay entre los 2?

Comment: ¿Con `DataTable` te refieres a la clase expuesta en la tecnología de .Net, o te refieres a un `DataTable` de JavaScript o exactamente a qué tipo y tecnología?

Comment: En pocas palabras: DataTable != Gird de jQuery. DataTable hace referencia al backend, es decir, la manera que estructuras los datos internamente y al mostrar informacion en el frontend te han recomendado usar la Grid jQuery. Saludos :D

Answer (score 1):

Yo te recomiendo ampliamente utilizar este plugin:

[DataTables Table plug-in for jQuery](https://datatables.net/)

Ya contiene mucha de la funcionalidad esperada en un grid y es muy rapido en el explorador.

Los controles propios del `ASP` creo que es el `gridview` el cual se puede en lazar con un `DataTable de .net` hacen mas lenta y pesada la aplicación, con **Jquery DataTables** tienes la posibilidad de utilizar una llamada `Ajax` a un método de `asp.net` para obtener los datos, es muy fluido y mas fácil de utilizar.

[Este es el ejemplo de jquery datatables con ajax](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta liga hay un ejemplo de como utilizarlo con asp.net (Nota: esta en ingles):

[Ejemplo jquery DataTable asp.net](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1011531/Using-jQuery-DataTables-with-Server-Side-Processin)

Comment: Vale muchas gracias probaré de utilizar ese plugin, pero que diferencia hay entre un jquery DataTable y un jquery Grid como el de esta pagina http://js-grid.com/?

Comment: No he utilizado el jquery Grid, deja lo reviso y lo añado a la respuesta

Comment: valee muchas gracias